# use Node v6.x and pm2 cause koa-ejs an Error

Tags: node.js, koa, pm2

When I use node v6.x and pm2 to start a serve, there will be an error:

```
TypeError: Iterator result <!DOCTYPE html>
....
</html> is not an object
at Object.app.context.render (/Users/..../project/node_modules/koa-ejs/index.js:98:23)
at next (native)
at onFulfilled (/Users/..../project/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)
```

but I won't get this error in any one of these cases:

- Node v4.x with pm2
- Node v6.x without pm2

I wonder what causes this bug?

Answer (score 0):

When you use Node v6.x, try starting `pm2` without `args`:

```
-node-args="--harmony"
```